# style and fontsize combobox Codenameone

Tags: combobox, styles, codenameone

I am developing a an app where in i use a combobox.

i like to change the font size and backgroundcolor of the combobox and de comboboxpopup. How do i do this, without css.

in the theme.res i can change the backgrondcolor of the comboboxpopup but not of the combobox. This stays grey, also when i changed the color in theme.res.

Also with code it doesn't change. What is the right way, can somebody give me an example.

```
  combotijden.getAllStyles().setBorder(Border.createEmpty(),true);
        combotijden.getAllStyles().setBgColor(0xffa500, true);
        combotijden.getAllStyles().setFgColor(0xFFFFFF, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ComboBox` is a `List` and as a result uses a renderer to draw itself. You need to style the renderer and not just the `ComboBox`. Easiest way is possibly:

```
Style rendererStyle = ((Component)combo.getRenderer()).getAllStyles();
```

This is pretty bad form since I rely on the fact that the `DefaultCellRenderer` is a component. That's part of why we recommend using a `Picker` but that is even less customizable. See [this post](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-dont-use-combobox.html) for more alternatives.

BTW instead of hardcoding numbers it's often best to just invoke `setUIID(String)` and then have several pre-configured looks in the CSS. That way you can still keep the theme separate and configurable.

Comment: i tried your solution but i am getting symbol combo not found , i added import com.codename1.ui.plaf.Style; What's wrong?

Comment: Which symbol isn't found? Can you include the full error?

Comment: Message is in Netbeans Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\Stroomatlas\build\tmp
C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\Stroomatlas\src\com\Bellproductions\Stroomatlas\Stroomatlas.java:467: error: cannot find symbol
   rendererStyle = ((Component)combo.getRenderer()).getAllStyles();
  symbol:   variable combo
  location: class Stroomatlas

Comment: You need to change the name `combo` to match the name of your variable. I believe you used `combotijden`.